# Install USB D-Link WIFI - disable onboard also

Tags: wireless, 22.04

Trying to setup a USB Wifi device on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

PN:CWA181CA.. ...A1

Driver pack downloaded from D-links site.
"RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.7.1_35809.20191129_COEX20191120-7777"

```
~$ lspci |grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 064e:a103 Suyin Corp. Acer/HP Integrated Webcam [CN0314]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c245 Logitech, Inc. G400 Optical Mouse
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
***Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2001:331e D-Link Corp. 802.11ac NIC***
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I have tried many guides / recommendations

I am a bit of a noob on Linux and Ubuntu but i have daily'd Ubuntu on another laptop for a while usually i can get things going.  but this is stumping me.

any help would be apreciated

Comment: I will be very surprised if the USB wireless outperforms the usually very capable Intel 7260. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential bc dkms
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702.git
cd 88x2bu-20210702
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

To disable the internal device, please do:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r iwlwifi
echo "blacklist iwlwifi" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```