# Can't access any info about network

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I just updated from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 and my system now shows no network connection. If I try to access the network tabs on System Settings or Info Center, I get an endless pinwheel and it seems to crash the program (i.e., can't switch to another tab, if I close the program it says it is not responding and won't close). Same with running

```
lshw -C network
```

and iwconfig in console - I get no result and eventually I just have to close the console window and kill the process.

I use a Realtek AC1200 USB wireless adaptor. If I run lsusb, it shows up correctly.

I really don't know much about Ubuntu, so any help would be greatly appreciated. This isn't the only thing that's gone wrong with the update, but I want to tackle one problem at a time!

Edit:

lsusb result:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1d6b:0102 Linux Foundation EEM Gadget
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I think this is all correct, but if there were any typos it's probably due to human error, as I had to transcribe it onto my other device. Other than the network adapter, I have a Logitech USB keyboard/mouse and a Nexigo webcam.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS had two *supported & QA-tested* upgrade paths; to the next release (ie. Ubuntu 18.10), or to the next LTS namely Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  Your description suggests you upgraded using an *unsupported* path, so issues maybe expected.  If that's what you did, you might want to consider a re-install. You didn't specify what Ubuntu product you're using (Server, Desktop etc), but Ubuntu Desktop systems can be re-installed without loss of data/configuration & *manually installed* packages will auto-reinstall (where they are available from official Ubuntu repositories).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 edited to include lsusb results.

Comment: Did you previously try and fail to install a driver? Please show us: `sudo dkms status` Here is the correct method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434501/install-usb-d-link-wifi-disable-onboard-also/1434604#1434604

Comment: @chili555 The process just runs indefinitely without returning any result. Another interesting twist that I just noticed: running ANY command with sudo seems to freeze the process. Even running

```

Comment: Even running "sudo ls -a", for example, does not return a result and leaves the process running until I close the console window.

Comment: I suggest that you search here for "sudo hangs". I regret that I haven't the answer.